# Smart Copy Paste/Replace in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a lot of lines like this in my program,

```
Current[0][1] - CILH.Offset;
```

Now I have to change all of them to:

```
this.Offset(Current[0][1], CILH.Offset);
```

Do I have to manually change this or there is some function or smart stuff in visual studio that can do this?

**UPDATE**

ok here is teh story, I have lines like this

```
double something0 = Current[0][1] - CILH.Offset; //both vars on right side are doubles
double something1 = Current[1][1] - CILH.Offset;
double something2 = Current[2][1] - CILH.Offset;
```

I had some problems so I decided to pass both right side doubles to a method and use the method instead:

```
private void Offset(double val, double off)
{
if(off == 0) return val;
else if(val == 0) return off;
else return val + off;
}
```

Now I have to change all lines to something like this:

```
double something0 = Offset(Current[0][1], CILH.Offset);
double something1 = Offset(Current[1][1], CILH.Offset);
double something2 = Offset(Current[2][1], CILH.Offset);
```

This is insane for hundred lines like this :(

Comment: Show more examples - it is impossible to answer this based on a single example without being able to extract the common bits.

Comment: Can you add an example of a few more lines that you're trying to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use regular expression for this you can look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/vstudioregexfind.aspx) for more details